# Removing resource files from final apk

Tags: android, gradle

I analyze apks a lot and try to optimize and reduce as much and wherever applicable. 
I would like to know how do i go about removing resources which might get imported from the libraries eg[common_google_login_btn_text..9.png etc]

These are not being used anywhere in the project but they are present in the final apk.[image]

Is there a way I could remove this `drawable-xxhdpi-v4` completely?

Any suggestions? apart from apk splitting.

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidStudio

Refactor -> Remove Unused Resoursces -> Refactor

You can implement resConfigs to your project to restrict resources. Add the following code to the build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
// ...
resConfigs "en"
resConfigs "nodpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi"
}
```

You can also use shrinkResources true to reduce app size.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

You can use `splits`. Add the following in `build.gradle`.

```
android {
 ...
splits {

// Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
density {

  // Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
  enable true

  // Specifies a list of screen densities Gradle should not create multiple APKs for.
  exclude "ldpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi" // Exclude what you don't require
}}}
```

Reference Documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Reference Documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html

Comment: This gave an apt error, upon running --stacktrace it itself is suggesting using splits.